# How to parse different packet types depending on first byte

Tags: java, buffer, preon

I'm trying to parse mysql result packets using preon. Packet looks like this:

`nn xx yy yy yy zz zz zz`

I parse it like this

```
class ResponsePacket {
  @BoundNumber(size="1")
  byte sizeOfThePacket;
  /* 
  if(xx==00)
    packet = OkResponsePayload(yy yy zz zz zz)
  elseif(xx==ff)
    packet = ErrorResponsePayload(yy yy zz zz zz)
  else
    packet = ResultResponsePayload(xx yy yy zz zz zz)
  */

  PacketPayload packet;

}
```

I tried using `@BoundObject` annotation like this:

```
    @BoundObject( selectFrom = @Choices(prefixSize = 8, 
        defaultType=ResultsResponsePacketPayload.class, 
        alternatives={
            @Choice(type=OkResponsePacketPayload.class, condition="prefix==0"),
            @Choice(type=ErrorResponsePacketPayload.class, condition="prefix==255")
        }))
```

It works perfectly fine for `OkResponsePayload` and `ErrorResponsePayload`, but `ResultResponsePayload` `Codec` doesn't have acces anymore to first byte used for prefix identification.

My first idea was to write custom `Codec<ResponsePacket>`, and inside decode i could read first byte and depending on it's value i could instantiate new codecs to parse rest of the buffer.

The problem in such case is that i wont have information on the total size of the packet(`nn`) which is sometimes usefull in expressions. 
Also it looks like there are other structures whiche behave like this(first byte decides of the type), wo this would require a lot of code writen by hand.

I hope someone could show me a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

Then don't use prefix, you have entire resolver context in condition available.

```
@BoundNumber(size = "8")
public int fieldNotPrefix;

@BoundObject( selectFrom = @Choices(
    defaultType=ResultsResponsePacketPayload.class, 
    alternatives={
        @Choice(type=OkResponsePacketPayload.class, condition="fieldNotPrefix==0"),
        @Choice(type=ErrorResponsePacketPayload.class, condition="fieldNotPrefix==255")
    }))
```

This way you will be able to reference fieldNotPrefix in limbo expressions as outer.fieldNotPrefix

Comment: This way I won't have acces to fieldNotPrefix bytes in ResultsResponsePacketPayload, please read carefully first pseudocode.

Comment: I think sakfa was saying that you _can_ get access to fieldNotPrefix by making `ResultsResponsePacketPayload` and all of the subclasses inner classes of `ResponsePacket`, and then - if you _need_ access to the `fieldNotPrefix` attribute, refer to it from these inner classes by `ResponsePacket.this.fieldNotPrefix`.